# Turn my text into any color in VBA for length longer than 5 characters

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make my string turn into green color if my len is bigger then 5.
 Here is my code. Can anyone help me out, I keep getting this error:

> Object doesn't support this property

```
Sub deme()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 1
    Dim cc As String
    Dim i As Long

    lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
    For i = a To lastrow
        cc = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        If Len(cc) > 5 Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Character(cc, i).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this using VBA? Why not use *Conditional Formatting*?

Answer (score 0):

It will fail on this line:

```
cc = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i)
```

because `Range()` returns a range and cc is a string.

It will fail on this line:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Character(cc, i).Font.Color = vbRed
```

because `Character()` only takes one parameter.

Give this a try:

```
Sub deme()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Long

  lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
  For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Len(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).text) > 5 Then
      for a = 5 to Len(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).text)
        Worksheets("sheet1").range("C" & i).Character(a).Font.Color = vbRed
      next
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Also, note that this line:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").range("C" & i).Character(a).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Will set the all but the first 5 characters red. Your question wanted to set them to green, so use `vbGreen` instead.

If you want to set the whole cell contents to green, replace:

```
      for a = 5 to Len(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).text)
        Worksheets("sheet1").range("C" & i).Character(a).Font.Color = vbRed
      next
```

with

```
      Worksheets("Sheet1").range("C" & i).font.color = vbGreen
```

Comment: also i changed my code into this
 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Font.Color = vbRed and its working, thanks

Comment: Couple of points: first, it's `Characters` not `Character` and second, that does take 2 (optional) arguments.

Answer (score 0):

INSTEAD

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Character(cc, i).Font.Color = vbRed
```

I CHANGED IT TO

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA has `.Font.Color = vbRed` and question `I want to make my string turn into green color if my len is bigger then 5` so I suggest, with Record Macro if desired,  selecting ColumnC and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true;**:

```
=LEN(C1)>5
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Font, Color: green, OK, OK (stop recording).

This formats the last occupied cell if longer than 5 characters.